# Accessing a server side variable inside loop in Clientside JS

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place Server side Variable in javascript loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667836/place-server-side-variable-in-javascript-loop)

Sir here is my current code on aspx page but still its not working like array please help to do this.Actually I was using array to make markers on map but now i am trying to load array latlang values from DB to make markers on map.But after a long struggle i am still unable to do the exact

**Update**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.sqlclient" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Permissions" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>GPS</title>

  <script runat=server>

      Dim mgps As New Text.StringBuilder
      Public ReadOnly Property GPS() As String
          Get
              Return mgps.ToString
          End Get
      End Property
      Sub Page_Load()

      End Sub
  </script>  

  <%  Dim con As New OleDbConnection
      con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
      con.Open()
      Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select STA_NAME, GPS_ONE from GPS", con)

      Dim ds As New DataSet
      Dim I As Long

      Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
      da.Fill(ds, "GPS")
      mgps.AppendLine("[")
      For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
          mgps.AppendLine(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & ",")
      Next I
      mgps.AppendLine("];")

      con.Close()
      %>  


    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var map;

 var markers = new Array();

 function initialize() {
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556);


   var GPS = <%=GPS %>

     var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      scaleControl:true,
      pancontrol: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      center: map_center,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


    //Start Loop

    for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
    {

          var image = 'ico/no.png';
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var ContentString = 'SML';
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
          { 
           position: GPS[i],
           map: map,
           draggable:true,
           icon:image,
           title: "ADeel" + (i+1)
           });                       
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(ContentString);
            infowindow.open(map,markers[i]);
            });


    }    
      }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="text-align: center">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%; text-align: center;">
      </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```