# Place Server side Variable in javascript loop

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

I have a Server side variable by the following code

```
 Dim mgps As New Text.StringBuilder
    Public ReadOnly Property GPS() As String
        Get
            Return mgps.ToString
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select STA_NAME, GPS_ONE from GPS", con)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim I As Long
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "GPS")

        mgps.AppendLine("[")
        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            mgps.AppendLine(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & ",")
        Next I
        mgps.AppendLine("];")
    End Sub
```

The Variable is Global named GPS

Now I am trying to access it in client side JS Array
JS Array is below

```
 var store_locations = new Array();
    store_locations = [ 
       new google.maps.LatLng(31.204549793299,72.264183974237),
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.23004996385,72.282225091978),
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.148218,72.224542),
        new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556)
        ];
```

Now I want to use GPS varible values instead of custome values in store_locations.

How can it be done anyone please help me.

Here is my loop where I want to access the array values.

```
 for(i=0; i<store_locations .length-1; i++)
    {

          var image = 'ico/no.png';
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
          { 
           position: store_locations [i],
           map: map,
           draggable:true,
           icon:image,
           title: (i+1) + GPS
           });                             
    }
```

I have access the GPS variable as below

```
var GPS = <%=GPS %>
```

and replace the store_locations with GPS but my map become empty.

Please tell me what exactly i am missing to do this?

Comment: How Can it be append any example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a public property that returns GPS value in code-begind. Create a `String` or `StringBuilder` object and define public property.

```
Dim mgps As new Text.StringBuilder

Public ReadOnly Property GPS As String
  Get
     Return mgps.ToString
  End Get
End Property
```

Use mgps (stringbuilder) object to add data from database result.

```
mgps.AppendLine("[")
For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
    mgps.AppendLine(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & ",")
Next I
mgps.AppendLine("];")
```

Now you can use GPS in JavaScript:

```
 var  GPS = <%=GPS %>
```

Comment: Yes it is Giving Coordinates values which are stored in Db On message.U can check it here http://202.125.144.34/Map/GPS.aspx

Comment: Sir Please answer to my question i have long struggle for this but still map is empty

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your GPS variable is inside the for loop (in your server side code) - therefore it does not exist outside of that.

I'm not entirely certain what you are trying to do, because right now you are not persisting the values outside of the loop, but declaring the GPS variable before your loop will at least allow you to gain access to it where you are currently trying to.

EDIT:
It should wind up looking something like this:

```
    da.Fill(ds, "GPS")
    Dim GPS As String
    For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
        I = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
        GPS = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE")
        Dim STATION As String = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("STA_NAME")
    Next I
```

Comment: Sir through your code GPS is returning only last value of Loop how can i access all loop values outside of the loop

Comment: That is because of your code Adeel...the iterator of you For...Next loop ("I" in this case) will go from 0 to the Rows.Count-1 value.  You then have a line that is overriding the value and setting it to Rows.Count-1.  Why do you have that line in your original post?  A For...Next loop automatically increases the value of I on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind you are appending VB lines to your StringBuilder that you return to the client.  So I'd imagine your client-side rendered code (do a View Source after page loads to confirm) shows this in the javascript:

```
var GPS1 = 'gps_line_1
gps_line_2
gps_line_3';
```

Change the following line:

```
mgps.AppendLine(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE"))
```

to:

```
mgps.Append(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE"))
mgps.Append("\n")
```

This way the client-side rendered javascript will be this:

```
var GPS1 = 'gps_line_1\ngps_line_2\ngps_line_3';
```

Comment: Well I know this question and your other question was similar but the code you posted was not.  My answer is based on the code you posted in "Assign Vb.net loop variable values to javascript Array" question.  Now that "Will" has combined them, this answer doesn't apply to your code on this question.